# How to replace all words of length less than 3 in a string with " " (space) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace

I am accessing a textfield named area which contains following text:

```
The First Backward Classes
Commission was formed in
1953 as chairman.
Joachim Alva
ﬁ    
Hardekar Manjappa 
Kaka Kalelkar
```

and I want to remove all words in this text which are of length less than 3 so that I can get a textfield containing text :

```
The First Backward Classes
Commission was formed
1953 chairman.
Joachim Alva
Hardekar Manjappa 
Kaka Kalelkar
```

I am using following code :

```
area.value = area.value.replace(/(\b(\w{1,2})\b(\W|$))/g,'').split(/\s+/).join( ' ' );
```

but the text that I get is :

```
First Backward Classes Commission formed 1953 chairman. Joachim Alva ﬁ Hardekar Manjappa Kaka Kalelkar
```

the whole text in textfield is converted into a single line which i don't want.
Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Split by newline, *then* do the replace and finally re-join with newlines.

Comment: can you please show me edited code for that?

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Comment: Are you aware that the `(\W|$))` part of your regex might match something else than a space ? For instance `Yo! I am a rebel` will be transformed into " rebel" (the space comes is the one after the exclamation point)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach which does two regex replacements.  The first replacement strips words of length 2 or less, and the second replacement removes extra newline whitespace.

```js
var input = "The First Backward Classes\nCommission was formed in\n1953 as chairman.\nJoachim Alva\nfi\nHardekar Manjappa\nKaka Kalelkar\n";
input = input.replace(/\b\w{1,2}\b[ \t]*/sg, "").replace(/\n+(?=\n)/g, "");
console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
area.value = area.value.split("\n") // split by newline
                       .map((s) => s.replace(/(\b(\w{1,2})\b(\W|$))/g,'')) // replace in each element
                       .join('\n'); // re-insert newlines (if that's what you want to do)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```js
var data = "The First Backward\n Classes\n Commission was formed in\n1953 as chairman.\nJoachim Alva\nﬁ\nHardekar Manjappa\nKaka Kalelkar";
var result = data.split('\n').map((line) => 
  line.split(' ').filter(str => str.length >3)
)
console.log(result.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = area.value.split('\n');
var x='';
for(var i=0;i>lines.length;i++){
x+=lines[i].replace(/(\b(\w{1,2})\b(\W|$))/g,'').split(/\s+/).join( ' ' );
}
area.value=x;
```

Comment: Sory I replace it with the JavaScript += , I use my iPhone and also It is php concatenation in my mind